# How to get distinct results joining 3 MySql tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-4

I have three tables in my database. See my tables--

```
Users Table:
user_id  name     email       phone     password  role
  38     Asif      ----        ----      ----      ---
  39     Anil      ----        ----      ----      ---
```

```
Flats Table:
flat_id block  flat_number  owner_id  area   rate
  1       B       B101        38      ---    ---
  2       A       A101        39      ---    ---
```

```
Payments Table: 
pay_id   flat_id   month_from   month_to   amount   date 
  1        1        ------       ------     ----     ---
  2        2        ------       ------     ----     ---
  28       1        ------       ------     ----     ---
```

When I join these table using this code:

```
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('payments p');
$builder->select('*');
$builder->join('flats f', 'f.flat_id = p.flat_id', 'left');
$builder->join('users u', 'u.user_id = f.owner_id', 'left'); 
$query = $builder->get(); 
$data['table_joined'] = $query->getResult();
```

I get these results:

```
FlatNumber  Name    PaidUpto     LastPaid
 B101       Asif   Sep 5, 2020    ----
 A101       Anil   Oct 5, 2020    ----
 B101       Asif   Oct 5, 2020    ----
```

The problem is I am getting one duplicate record of user Asif, these are three records. But, I want two records only because there are two users only. That means I want number of results equal to records in users table and no duplicates.

Please suggest me a solution to get that done...

Comment: so what result you want??

Comment: I want results equal to the number of users.